# Apache server loads page instead of applying rewrite rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make my website add a trailing slash and then rewrite the URI to an `html` page. Basically redirect `xy.com/abc` to `xy.com/abc/`, and then actually load `xy.com/abc.html`.

My `.htaccess` file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1/ [R]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ $1.html [L]
```

When I try going to `xy.com/asd` (non-existing page) it redirects to `xy.com/asd/` and gives me a proper 404 error.

When I try it with a page that actually exists (`xy.com/about`), it just loads `xy.com/about.html` without redirecting at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ $1/ [R,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$ $1.html [L,NC]
```

Comment: Awesome, `Options -MultiViews` solves the problem on its own. Thanks a lot. Do I understand correctly that the RewriteCond checks if an html file with the right name exists before trying to load it? What difference does it make if it 404's anyway?

Comment: Yes indeed `RewriteCond` makes sure `.html` file exists before adding `.html` extension. Also both rules need `L` flag.